# Do... while loop in Java

Tags: java, do-while

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong here??  I'm getting caught in an infinite loop.

```
do{
    System.out.print("cards["+pickRandom+"] is:"+cards[pickRandom]);
    pickRandom = (int)(Math.random() * 52);  //pick a new random card
    System.out.print(" so now cards["+pickRandom+"] is:"+cards[pickRandom]);
    if (cards[pickRandom] != 0) {  //if it's not 0, then assign it
        System.out.print("cards["+pickRandom+"] is not 0: "+cards[pickRandom]);
        shuffled[k]=cards[pickRandom];
        System.out.print(" shuffled["+k+"]:"+shuffled[k]);
        cards[pickRandom]=0;
        //System.out.println("For card "+k+ ": "+ shuffled[k] +" was found on pick number "+count);
    } 
    else{System.out.println("cards["+ pickRandom+ " was:" +cards[pickRandom]);}
}while (cards[pickRandom]==0);
```

---

I am trying to pick a random card that is not ==0. If it is ==0, I want the loop to pick another card

Comment: See edit to answer, move your `cards[pickRandom]=0;` to **after** the do-while loop

Answer (score 2):

Your if block is guaranteed to change any `cards[pickRandom]` that's non-zero to 0. And doing this will mean that your while condition is always true.

So in essence, this is your code's logic:

```
int x = 1;
do { 
   x = // some random value
   if (x != 0) {
      x = 0;
   }
while (x == 0);
```

Solution: don't do this. Use some other way to end your loop. For more detailed help, please explain your code and its goals in more detail.

---

A possible solution to your problem: set your array value to zero **after** the while loop:

```
  do {
     pickRandom = (int) (Math.random() * 52);
     if (cards[pickRandom] != 0) {
        shuffled[k] = cards[pickRandom];

        //  cards[pickRandom] = 0; // *** don't do this here ***

     } else {
        // not sure what you want here
     }
  } while (cards[pickRandom] != 0);

  cards[pickRandom] = 0;  // **** do it here! ****
```

The reason being, at that point, you'll know that a correct card has been picked. One problem though -- consider testing to make sure that all values in cards are not 0.

Better solution: use an ArrayList of Integers, shuffle them with `Collections.shuffle()`, and then simply remove the 0th item from the loop each time, as long as size() > 0.

Comment: Yes - an arrayList is the next step.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your `cards[pickRandom]` to `0` in each case-

```
cards[cards[pickRandom]=0;
```

And after that you check condition in while loop -

```
while (cards[pickRandom]==0);
```

So in the condition in while loop always evaluated to `true` and that's why the loop continues for ever without stopping.

Comment: I am trying to pick a random card that is not ==0.  

If it is ==0, I want the loop to pick another card.

Comment: @JeffCiaccio: this information doesn't belong buried in a comment. Please improve your question so that we understand your variables and your goals, and so that everyone who reads your question knows this, not just folks who look at comments down here.

Comment: In case then when your loop should stop. If we know that than it will be easier to fix the code.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels, how do I change the question?  I don't see an edit for the original question.

Comment: @JeffCiaccio: the comment was mine, not Razib's. You edit it by clicking on the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29330948/edit) at the bottom of your question. I've added the information from your comment, but we need more. Please provide as much pertinent information as possible.

Comment: @Jeff Ciaccio, the `edit` link should be just under the `java` and `do while` tag. If you can't still see it probably someone editing your question.